# Exporting specific instance of a class in Python

Tags: python, module, pickle

I have a custom class that inherits from scikit-learns `MinMaxScaler`. This class is fitted to a dataset and later on reused to perform scaling and the reverse of multiple other datasets.

So far, I have pickled the file and reused it in the same directory as I continue to use it. But now I need to move the .pkl file to a different location to access it there and also make it accessible for any person (who most likely won't have access to the same data as I do). As soon as I want to open it now I get an `ImportError: No module named 'Preprocess_Hist_Data'`. I guess this is because pickle is not really used for a scenario like that. Is there a possibility to accomplish what I am trying? Maybe something that incorporates the whole class definition upon saving? I would appreciate any input.

Comment: Pickle does not support that. Check out alternative serialization mechanisms, such as [dill](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill).

Comment: I tried using dill, but got the exact same error.

Comment: Well I haven't used it myself, I only put it because I _think_ it's among its supposed features.